# Aggregate dataframe with many columns per week

Tags: r, dplyr, timestamp, tidyr

I have a large dataframe with many columns and a timestamp  [(see picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irULJ.png)
What I am trying to do is to aggregate the data per week for all columns. Any suggestions?

Kind regards,
Daniel

Comment: Hello Daniel. Please review [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a minimal reproducible example it's difficult to know exactly which function to use to summarize the data (sum, mean, median, etc.).

For now we'll assume that each row represents a day or some more granular unit (since the date column is called `Timestamp` and we can't see whether there are actual time values in the field).

We use a combination of `tidyr`, `dplyr` and `lubridate` to create a summarized data frame that sums the data in the columns.

First, we generated some raw data that is in a format similar to the data in the screen shot, and read it into R.

```
rawData <- "Timestamp,Var.2,Amazonas,Antioquia,Arauca
2022-01-01,0,0,0,1
2022-01-02,0,0,1,3
2022-01-03,0,1,1,2
2022-01-04,0,0,1,0
2022-01-05,0,2,0,0
2022-01-06,3,0,2,2
2022-01-07,2,3,0,2
2022-01-08,1,0,0,0
2022-01-09,0,1,3,0
2022-01-10,0,0,0,0
2022-01-11,0,2,0,5
2022-01-12,0,0,3,0
2022-01-13,0,3,0,4
2022-01-14,0,0,4,0
2022-01-15,0,0,0,3
2022-01-16,0,0,0,0
2022-01-17,0,3,0,0
2022-01-18,0,0,2,3
2022-01-19,0,0,0,0
2022-01-20,0,2,0,0
2022-01-21,0,0,5,2
2022-01-22,0,0,0,0
2022-01-23,0,1,0,0
2022-01-24,0,0,3,1
2022-01-25,0,1,0,1
2022-01-26,0,0,0,1
2022-01-27,0,2,0,0
2022-01-28,0,2,0,1
2022-01-29,0,0,1,0
2022-01-30,0,0,1,0"

df <- read.csv(text = rawData,
               colClasses = c("Date","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric"))
```

Next, we load the required libraries. From `lubridate` package we'll use the `year()` and `week()` functions to group the data by week of the year.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
```

Finally, we use `tidyr::pivot_longer()` to create long format tidy data where each row represents one day's observations for one column in the wide format data frame, create the `Year` and `Week` columns, and `summarise()` the remaining columns in the data frame.

```
df %>% pivot_longer(-Timestamp,names_to="Area") %>%
     mutate(Year = year(Timestamp),
            Week = week(Timestamp)) %>%
     group_by(Year,Week,Area) %>%
     summarise(summedValue = sum(value)) -> summarisedData

head(summarisedData)
```

...and the first few rows of output:

```
> head(summarisedData)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   Year, Week [2]
   Year  Week Area      summedValue
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
1  2022     1 Amazonas            6
2  2022     1 Antioquia           5
3  2022     1 Arauca             10
4  2022     1 Var.2               5
5  2022     2 Amazonas            6
6  2022     2 Antioquia          10
>
```

If we need the data in the original format (wide format tidy data), we can use `pivot_wider()` to restore the data to its original shape.

```
# if necessary, pivot_wider() to restore data to original format
summarisedData %>%
     pivot_wider(id_cols=c("Year","Week"),
                 names_from=Area,
                 values_from=summedValue)
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 6
# Groups:   Year, Week [5]
   Year  Week Amazonas Antioquia Arauca Var.2
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2022     1        6         5     10     5
2  2022     2        6        10      9     1
3  2022     3        5         7      8     0
4  2022     4        6         3      4     0
5  2022     5        0         2      0     0
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

[1] Never provide pictures of data; provide data.

[2] The answer depends on how you define "week". For instance, 2022-01-01 was a Saturday. The ISO 8601 standard defines a week to begin on Monday, so week 1 in 2022 started on Jan 3. Jan 1 & 2 were technically part of the last week in 2021. The `week(...)` function in lubridate counts in 7 day increments from whatever is the first day of the year. So obviously you will get different answers.

Here is a very simple way to do this using data.table, borrowing the minimum reproducible example kindly provided by @LenGreski (**you** should do this).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=.(year=year(Timestamp), week=isoweek(Timestamp))]

##    year week Var.2 Amazonas Antioquia Arauca
## 1: 2022   52     0        0         1      4
## 2: 2022    1     6        7         7      6
## 3: 2022    2     0        5         7     12
## 4: 2022    3     0        6         7      5
## 5: 2022    4     0        5         5      4
```

The first clause, `setDT(df)`, converts `df` to a  data.table. The remaining part applies the `sum(...)` function to a subset of the columns in the data.table referenced by `.SD`. The default subset is all columns except ones referenced in the `by=...` clause (so, all columns except `Timestamp`).